# SQL - Blank value

Tags: sql-server

I do a join between two tables A and B.
The result set is copied to target table C.

For cross checking , I do the join between all three tables based on the common column.
for a matching record ,  C.yyy = a.xxx should be the case. This works fine for non-blank value and null values.
But the issue is with the Blank strings. When a.xxx is blank c.yyy should also be blank . This is fine in one environment. But in another environment c.yyy becomes null when a.xxx is blank .

The behaviour changes in one environment. Why is that so?

Note: The query is the same in both environments. Also both the fields are Varchar.

Comment: Can you provide the table creation script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your current question is not really answerable because you omitted critical information, such as the query and data to which you are referring.  Please show the query and data.

Answer (score 0):

The result of blank and null comparison depends on the ANSI NULL and ANSI Padding settings of your environment. When comparing varchar's containing blanks or trailing spaces, you should use the LIKE operator because it takes all characters into account, regardless of the padded length.
See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626 for further information.